# Create new Project in self-hosted GitLab instance

Tags: git, gitlab, repository, remote-repository

I have a problem that I can't create a new project in self-hosted GitLab instance. Every time I try to create an error appear "namespace is not valid". I spent yesterday trying solving the problem. then I contact the support in GitLab, they told me to contact the administrator, but I want to know should I get permission from admin to create a new project?

Also, I try to clone this repo as remotely to another project in command line but also I failed.

Any suggestions, please.

thanks in advance,

Comment: It looks like Gitlab bug to me. I can reproduce that for users with LDAP settings like:
`LDAP uid: cn=name lastname,ou=services,ou=user,ou=company,dc=company,dc=local.  ` Users with only one `ou` don't have this problem. 
Now, I don't know are you using ldap as well in your instance.

Answer (score 2):

Check the "*Allowed to create projects*" setting in the group settings area.

The answer from https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/3941#note_114177915

Go to your group's settings page, similar to: `https://gitlab.com/groups/groupname/-/edit`

Expand the "*Permissions, LFS, 2FA*" section and below the LFS section will be the "*Allowed to create projects*" setting where you can choose which is the minimum role required to create a project.